# How can I write a nested serializer that behaves differently when writing or reading?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am looking for a way to create a nested serializer which will behave differently when writing or reading.  In my specific case, I have some models that look like this:

```py
class Frame(models.Model):
    frame_stack = models.IntegerField()
    frame_reach = models.IntegerField()
    # ...

class CustomBicycle(models.Model):
    frame = models.ForeignKey(Frame)
    # ...
```

When the CustomBicycle model is serialized, I want it to look like this:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "frame": {
        "id": 1,
        "frame_stack": 123,
        "frame_reach": 234
    }
}
```

Let's say I want to submit some JSON to be de-serialized in order to update the above CustomBicycle instance.  In that case, I'd like to submit the following JSON in order to update its Frame to the one with id = 2:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "frame": {
        "id": 2,
        "frame_stack": 345,
        "frame_reach": 456
    }
}
```

The serializer I need would look at the "frame.id" property in the JSON and then update the CustomBicycle instance to point to Frame #2.  It would ignore all other properties under the "frame" key in the JSON (but it should allow those properties to be there).

The reason I want this is that I have something analogous to model classes in the Javascript of my application.  I can easily serialize these Javascript model instances into JSON that looks like that which is above.  I don't want to have to program in extra logic to serialize the model data in the ways that would be necessary to work with a flat JSON API, as is required by the current version of Django Rest Framework.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own kinda hacky solution to this one:

```py
class NestedForeignKeyAssignmentMixin(object):
    def field_from_native(self, data, files, field_name, into):
        if self.read_only:
            return

        value = data.get(field_name)
        id = value.get('id') if value else None

        if not id:
            if self.required:
                raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'])
            into[field_name] = None
            return

        model = self.Meta.model

        try:
            into[field_name] = model._default_manager.get(id=id)
        except model.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError('{name} with id `{id}` does not exist'.format(
                name=model.__name__,
                id=id,
            ))


class FrameSerializer(NestedForeignKeyAssignmentMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ...

    class Meta:
        model = Frame


class CustomBicycleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    frame = FrameSerializer()
    # ...
```